# Replace substring using regex but preserve spaces

Tags: javascript

I am replacing content in a string with a predetermined character based on if the substring is wrapped in quotes.

```
const string = "The \"quick\" brown \"fox\" 'jumps' over the 'lazy dog'";
const pattern = /(?:'([^']*)')|(?:"([^"]*)")/g;
const redactedText = string.replace(pattern, (str) => {
  const strippedString = str.replace(/['"]+/g, '');
  return 'x'.repeat(strippedString.length);
}
```

Output: The xxxxx brown xxx xxxxx over the xxxxxxxx

However I was to preserve the space within `lazy dog`

So it would output:
The xxxxx brown xxx xxxxx over the xxxx xxx

What am I missing to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use another `replace` for non space characters instead of `"x".repeat`

```js
const string = "The \"quick\" brown \"fox\" 'jumps' over the 'lazy dog'";
const pattern = /(?:'([^']*)')|(?:"([^"]*)")/g;
const redactedText = string.replace(pattern, (str) => {
  const strippedString = str.replace(/['"]+/g, '');
  
  return strippedString.replace(/[^\ ]/g,'x'); // replace non space character w/"x"
})
console.log(redactedText)
```